# Trigger performance tuning

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers, sp-send-dbmail

I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have a trigger that inserts into a table where asql agent job then kicks off every 10 sec's to run a sp to send an email notification. The problem that I'm running into is it appears that when a large number of inserts happen simultaneously the notifications can hang up and not get sent out for several minutes (sometimes as long as an hour) after the insert happens.The tb_BatchEmail only receives a few inserts (2-3) at a time, it's the Orders tables that can have several dozen inserts happen at once. So my question is - Is this the best way to setup this type of trigger or is there a better way that is more efficient and won't lag behind when loads of table inserts happen at once?

Here is the trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[VoceraOeOrders] ON [dbo].[Orders]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.tb_BatchEmail (
        BatchEmailID
        ,[To]
        ,Body
        ,[Subject]
        ,[Profile]
        ,OrderID
        ,OrderDateTime
        ,SentDateTime
        )
    SELECT '0'
        ,'some_email'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN RoomTreatmentID IS NULL
                THEN 'No Room#'
            ELSE RoomTreatmentID
            END + '-' + OrderedProcedureName
        ,CASE 
            WHEN Category = 'US'
                THEN 'Stat Ultra Sound'
            WHEN Category = 'NUC'
                THEN 'Stat Nuclear'
            WHEN Category = 'ECHO'
                THEN 'Stat Echo'
            WHEN Category = 'CT'
                THEN 'Stat C T'
            WHEN Category = 'MRI'
                THEN 'Stat M R I'
            WHEN Category = 'XRAY'
                THEN 'Stat Xray'
            ELSE 'Stat Order Alerts'
            END
        ,'Alert'
        ,OrderID
        ,OrderDateTime
        ,NULL
    FROM inserted i
    INNER JOIN dbo.Patients pat
        ON pat.VisitID = i.VisitID
            AND pat.SourceID = i.SourceID
    WHERE Priority = 'STAT'
        AND Category IN ('CT', 'MRI', 'XRAY', 'US', 'NUC', 'ECHO')
        AND CurrentLocationID = 'ED'
END
```

And here is the sp that is set to kick off every 10 seconds via server agent job:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SendVoceraMail]

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Id INT
DECLARE @To VARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @Body VARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @Subject VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ProfileName VARCHAR(20)

WHILE (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM tb_BatchEmail
        WHERE BatchEmailID = 0
        ) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @Id = Id
        ,@To = [To]
        ,@Body = Body
        ,@Subject = [Subject]
        ,@ProfileName = [Profile]
    FROM tb_BatchEmail
    WHERE BatchEmailID = 0

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = @To
        ,@body = @Body
        ,@subject = @Subject
        ,@profile_name = @ProfileName


    UPDATE tb_BatchEmail
    SET BatchEmailID = 1
        ,SentDateTime = GETDATE()
    WHERE Id = @Id
END

END
```

Comment: I would set the timer to a much bigger interval than every 10 seconds. Otherwise your process is likely stepping all over itself because it can't process everything before the next time it starts running. I would set the timer to something more realistic like 5-10 minutes or something. Is it critical that the email gets sent as absolutely fast as possible after the insert happens?

Comment: Yeah it's critical that it get's sent as soon as possible. This is actually for a hospital system to alert the appropriate people in real time when certain ER orders are placed. The email actually gets picked up and sent to hand held devices that the correct people have on them.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the send_mail. I very rarely have more than 2-3 orders that actually make it to he tb_BatchEmail table which is were the send_mail sp runs. The bottle neck appears to be on the orders trigger and table itself where there can be 50+ orders inserted/updated simultaneously that seems to effect when the trigger actually gets kicked off and inserts into the tb_BatchEmail table.

Comment: Can you tell when it gets slow if something is locking the patients table which is holding the trigger up for a bit?

Comment: There isn't anything that I can readily see that appears to be holding up the patients table.

Comment: And there certainly isn't anything that would be holding it up for 15, 20 or 60 mins.

Comment: I would use SELECT with UPDLOCK and wrap it in a transaction together with the UPDATE, to avoid problems when the procedure is started twice.